# Is it possible to create an actual working physics-based ball bearing in Roblox engine?

Tags: collision-resolution, physics-engine, simulations, vehicle

Will it allow for making actual wheels, gears and roller coasters?

Comment: Usually games don't simulate machines down to the individual components like ball bearings. A roller coaster would often be implemented as a body following a spline, for example, with some animation to spin the wheels as a cosmetic feature — they're not actually experiencing torques and keeping the cart on the track. What specifically do you want to make in Roblox, how have you tried implementing it so far, and what part do you need help with?

Comment: Yes, as @DMGregory said, you would probably have the wheel as an imported 3D model, and then create animations for it to make it look like it's rotating, although Roblox engine doesn't really have a lot of power compared to genuine game engines so I'm unsure how much you can do on it.

Comment: @DMGregory i was trying to do experimental gears rotating the other one, and succeeded; i was also thinking about making an invisible pulley / roller wheel underneath the wagon which will keep it on track while turning

Comment: You're likely to find that approach disappointing. Game physics engines are optimized for speed over accuracy or stability, so they don't tend to handle detailed mechanical interactions well. It'll work for a few gears at low speeds, but as your machine gets more complicated or moves faster, sometimes bits that should have collided will skip past each other or inter-penetrate and either seize together or get rocketed apart like a small explosion, or jitter and swim around like they're vibrating springs. I'd recommend simulating this at the highest level you can rather than modelling each part.

Comment: @DMGregory yes, i do understand how collision solvers work and how collision prediction error gets in the way sometimes, but rn i am looking at a system of 3 gears rotating at 50k degrees per second, the minor problem being that it skips one tooth sometimes (but the objective was never actual mechanical simulation - which will not be possible anyway since there is no notion of grease, metallic elasticity, heating or wearing off)

Comment: It sounds like you understand the obstacles you'll face in modelling ball bearing interactions, then. What new information are you hoping to glean from answers here?

Comment: @DMGregory first thing you should have responded in that the Village example in Roblox Studio features some gears, including the one transferring torque by 90 degrees, although teeth are definitely rigged so that collision solver has nothing to do with actual force there (they are dead flat everywhere and do not even touch each other while the system works, completely relying on prediction); there is also some kind of velocity limiter there, it seems